# How can i create a new language model for language other than english?

Tags: natural-language-processing, language-model

I have large set of corpus for all literature in 'Tamil' language, i am trying to create a document retrieval engine through simple natural language.

Since the corpus is huge, its hard to do a supervised learning, i also checked ai4bharat.org 's initiatives to build the language models, but its still not working good the literature texts.

what is required to build a model from scratch